# Javascript get image height works in all browsers but firefox...please help?

Tags: javascript, image, firefox, height

So I am fairly new to Javascript (a lot of experience in PHP), but I have this basic script that checks a link that redirects to a URL to see what the image height is.  If it is a certain height then it adds one to a variable, otherwise nothing.  I would easily do this in PHP but the images are on other servers and not my own so it doesn't work.

Anyways, ehre is the script.  Let me know if you have any tips.  Works well and tested in Chrome, Safari, Opera, and IE.

```
<script language='JavaScript'>
window.onload = function() {

var nstar = 0, urls = [];
urls[0] = "http://optout.imiclk.com/cgi/nai_status.cgi?nocache=";
urls[1] = "http://www.adbrite.com/mb/nai_optout_check.php?nocache=";
urls[2] = "http://events.adchemy.com/visitor/auuid/nai-status?nocache=";

function getImgSize(imgSrc){
    var newImg = new Image();
    newImg.src = imgSrc;
    return{height:newImg.height, width:newImg.width}
}

for(i=0,length=urls.length;i<length;i++){
    if(getImgSize(urls[i]).height==43){nstar++;}
}
document.getElementById('tracknum').innerHTML = "<b>" + nstar + "</b>";

}               

</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the image isn't loaded yet? 
Try :

```
image.onload=function() {
    alert('W:'+image.width+', H:'+image.height)
}
```

Comment: thanks for the hint but it wasn't showing the height or width. Just showing up as 0's.

Comment: @Calvin: Works for me in Firefox 3.6.13

Comment: Anonymous87 is correct.  The image has to finish downloading before you can query it's width/height properties.

Comment: Have you tried loading image from the same domain? There was a bug in old Firefox causing external src images not to load when using JavaScript to create the <img>. You can also try it on an image without redirect.

Comment: ah ok.  Well the image will always be on a seperate server and the links check to see if cookie is set then redirects accordingly.  Since that will differ between all web users computers, I can't post the direct links.